# C++ help copy constructor

Tags: c++, runtime-error, copy-constructor

I am a new at c++ and I need help with my program. So basically it is a program where you can create a character. I have used constructor, copy-constructor, and deconstructor to create it. Now there is a problem, every time I would run it, it would give me an error such as this

> Unhandled exception at 0x0F424F98 (msvcr110d.dll) in Copy
>   constructor.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0xFEEEFEE2

anyway here is my code and would appreciate it if you would take a look at it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Character {
private:
    string* name;
    int* age;
    char* gender;
public:
    //declaring constructor
    Character(const string pname, const int page, const char pgender) {
        cout << "Making new character" << endl;
        name = new string;
        age = new int;
        gender = new char;
        //assingment operator
        *name = pname;
        *age = page;
        *gender = pgender;
    }
    //declaring copy constructor
    Character(const Character& cName, const Character& cAge, const Character cGender) {
        cout << "Keeping a copy constructor" << endl;
        name = new string;
        age = new int;
        gender = new char;
        //assingment operator
        *name = *cName.name;
        *age = *cAge.age;
        *gender = *cGender.gender;
    }
    ~Character() {
        cout << "Deleting the character " << endl;
        delete name;
        delete age;
        delete gender;
    }
    //get name
    string getName() {
        return *name;
    }
    //get age
    int getAge() {
        return *age;
    }
    //get gender
    char getGender() {
        return *gender;
    }
};
void showCharacter(Character display) {
    cout << "Charater Name: " << display.getName() << endl; //get name
    cout << "Character Age: " << display.getAge() << endl; //get age
    cout << "Character Gender: " << display.getGender() << endl; //get gender 
}

int main() {
    //local variables
    string name;
    int age;
    char gender;
    //user interface
    cout << "Write your charaters name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Write your character's age: ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Write you character's gender: ";
    cin >> gender;
    //calling constructor
    Character detail(name,age,gender);
    //Showing result
    showCharacter(detail);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An official copy constructor takes only the reference to the object it's copying, not any other parameters. If you don't provide one the compiler will generate one for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copy constructor is meant to make a copy of the object.  So, the copy constructor prototype for you will be

```
Character ( const Character& c );
```

The one you have declared has three different parameters of type `Character`.  The complete constructor will be:

```
Character(const Character& cName){
    cout << "Keeping a copy constructor" << endl;
    name = new string;
    age = new int;
    gender = new char;
    //assingment operator
    *name = *(cName.name);
    *age = *(cName.age);
    *gender = *(cName.gender);
    }
```

Comment: So what should be the solution?

Comment: Replace your version of the copy constructor with the one described above.  One thing I did not understand was why you are using pointers/dynamic memory to create the object members.

Comment: Thanks mate also one question, Why is there just one parameter for the copy constructor? Shouldn't there be one parameter for each pointer

Comment: @Jim The copy constructor takes one parameter because it copies the data members from that object to the object being initialized.

Comment: @0x499602D2 has answered well.  Your mistake was that you were trying to copy three objects into one.  You just need the members from one object whom you are trying to copy.  There is no need to specify more than one in the parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

Jim,

What you are calling "Copy Constructor" is not really a copy constructor as the compiler understands it.

The signature of the copy constructor has to be:

```
Character(Character const& copy);
```

The implementation would be similar to the way you have defined your copy constructor.

```
Character(const Character& copy){
cout << "Keeping a copy constructor" << endl;
name = new string;
age = new int;
gender = new char;
//assingment operator
*name = *copy.name;
*age = *copy.age;
*gender = *copy.gender;
}
```

You can make things a whole lot simpler by declaring the data slightly differently. Instead of

```
string* name;
int* age;
char* gender;
```

You can use

```
string name;
int age;
char gender;
```

If you do that, you don't need an explicit copy constructor. The compiler defined copy constructor will work just fine. You can also let the compiler define the destructor for you.

Comment: But you wouldn't be able to free up space (via delete) after using it right? @R Sahu

Comment: The compiler defined destructor will free up the space used by "name" because it is going to call the destructor of std::string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your code will look like when using objects instead of pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Character {
  private:
    string name;
    int age;
    char gender;
  public:
    //declaring constructor
    Character(const string pname, const int page, const char pgender):
       name(pname), age(page), gender(pgender) {
         cout << "Making new character" << endl;
    }

    // NO need for explicit copy constructor or destructor.

    //get name
    string getName() {
        return name;
    }
    //get age
    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    //get gender
    char getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
};
void showCharacter(Character display) {
    cout << "Charater Name: " << display.getName() << endl; //get name
    cout << "Character Age: " << display.getAge() << endl; //get age
    cout << "Character Gender: " << display.getGender() << endl; //get gender 
}

int main() {
    //local variables
    string name;
    int age;
    char gender;
    //user interface
    cout << "Write your charaters name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Write your character's age: ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Write you character's gender: ";
    cin >> gender;
    //calling constructor
    Character detail(name,age,gender);
    //Showing result
    showCharacter(detail);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @R Sahu I will keep in mind also from seeing your program, it does saves a lot of time :) also like you said it will automatically free up space but will it be able to prevent memory leak from happening.